# Cryogenic Particle Detectors

Tags: particle-physics, neutrinos, elementary-particles, superfluidity

Recently, I started reading about Neutrinos, their types, oscillations and their detection.

Today many experiments are being conducted to detect and measure oscillations of sterile neutrinos and anti-neutrinos such as DUNE, SLAC and others. The common thing in all these experiments is use of liquid argon (cryogenic).

Someone please explain why supercooled substances are used for detection of Neutrinos.

Answer (score 3):

> [When a neutrino bumps](https://lbnf-dune.fnal.gov/how-it-works/detectors-and-computing/) into an argon atom’s core, it produces particles that knock loose electrons in the liquid argon. A high voltage draws these electrons to wire planes installed inside each detector module. This results in a distinctive, precise signal that yields important information about the neutrino interaction and allows for a 3D reconstruction of the particles’ trajectories.

The denser the target , the higher the probability of interaction and liquid argon is used , but also if you look at the [list of neutrino experiments,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_neutrino_experiments) liquid  Xenon and water etc is are used.